# How to generate random numbers from 0 to 100 without duplicates when user enters the size of the array in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linear-search

> Write a program to generate any number of random integers in 0 to 100
> range. Your program should get the size as a parameter and return the
> numbers as an array.

This the question I got and below is the code I tried, but I get duplicates with this code. How to generate random numbers without any duplicates?

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.println("size:\t");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
    
            int[] arr = new int[n];
    
            Random rand = new Random(); //instance of a random class.
            int upperbound = 101; //generate random values from 0-100
    
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                arr[i] = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
            }
            System.out.println("Random Numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list that contains all values from 0 to 100, then shuffle it and extract the first n elements of that list like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("size:\t");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int bound = 100;
        
        List<Integer> items = IntStream.range(0, bound + 1)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.shuffle(items);

        int[] arr = new int[Math.min(n, bound + 1)];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = items.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Random Numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashSet` and keep adding all the new entries to it and while generating a new `random` integer, check if it was already generated (if the number is present in the `unique` set).
If the number was already generated, then keep generating new number until a unique number is found.

```java
        Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            int number = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
            while (unique.contains(number)) // `number` is a duplicate
                number = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
            arr[i] = number;
            unique.add(number); // adding to the set
        }
```

Comment: If the size of the array gets closer to the range of random number you are generating it will take forever

Comment: @mont_ No that not true. I've verified the result for an array of size 100 and *upperbound* = 101, it works fine.

Comment: @javadev It took 0.12sec for generating 10000 unique numbers. So no, it won't.

Comment: @GURUShreyansh, indeed - for n=100 numbers, it will not take time that may effect a human eye. Yet, what about n=10000? n=100000? I didn't say it will not work, it will just take some more time (the resolution is probably not relevant in this case, but for some applications / higher numbers, it will take MUCH longer).

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned a range, i.e, `[0 - 100]`. So, 10^100 and all those fancy numbers are irrelevant for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of 1...100 (let's call in "l") , and an array of size 100 (let's call it "a").

Then, create a for loop and generate a number between 0 to l.size() - 1.

First iteration generation (let's call it index0) will be the index in l that will be taken as the first object in the array. So call l.remove(index0), and use the retrieved object in a[0].

Second iteration generation, between 0 to l.size()-1, which means 0 to 98. That will be index1. call l.remove(index1), the retrieved object will be used to the second index in a[1].

Do it until l is empty.

Answer (score 1):

this code work as well

```
public void solution(int size){


    int upperbound = 101;
    int arr[]=new int[upperbound];

    /**
     * initial a number arr store 0-100
     */
    for (int i = 0; i <upperbound ; i++) {
        arr[i]=i;
    }

    SecureRandom secureRandom=new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i <size ; i++) {

        /**
         * if generate a index, print number and swap now index number and tail
         */
        int index=secureRandom.nextInt(upperbound-i);
        int tmp=arr[index];
        int last=arr[arr.length-1-i];

        System.out.println(tmp);
        arr[index]=last;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Array you could use an ArrayList and add the value to the ArrayList only if it has not been used before.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
if (!numbers.contains(randomNumber)) {
    numbers.add(randomNumber);
}
```

After this you could directly the print the ArrayList or convert it into an array and then print it out.

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[number.size()];
    // ArrayList to Array Conversion
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = number.get(i);
```